# Getting UserID details into Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to get the Google UserID working so that I can identify certain users journeys through my website.

I've enabled the USER ID feature as per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id), which created a new view named Users in my Analytics account. There's data in there, but I can't see to separate it. It looks like a standard account.

How do I spilt data by the user ID I've given them?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Userid is not displayed. It is used to stitch user sessions together when users come from multiple devices, it does not identify individual users in the interface.

If you want to do that you have to use a custom dimension and store an identifier per user there.

Comment: For a very quick test, on Friday I amended my GA tracking code to send the userid 'dotty' if a user visited with my IP address (basically it should track me only, identified as dotty). Today, I've amended that user to 'dotty-monday'. Is there a way to identify which data belongs to which user? Because at the moment the view only shows traffic that has a userID.

Comment: If you read the docs you will see that this is intended behaviour; the user id view shows only visits with a user id. But it does not display the id anywhere in the interface - the id is just used so that analytics can recognize users across devices (and produce the cross device report). If you want to segment by user you have to use a custom dimension, and this does not work retroactively.

Comment: In that case what is the point of defining a userID per user? If every user is grouped as a single user? I guess what I'm getting at is ho can I give each user an ID, and track what activities a single user has been doing?